# Жуткие фризы в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Установил Elipse и в него допилил aCute для написания C# кода, суть в том, что помимо эклипса запущен только браузер с двумя вкладками, да хоть даже без браузера жуткие фризы в самом эклипсе, если чуть-чуть пописать код, то потом становится более менее терпимо, но при нажатии ПКМ постоянно ловлю фризы на секунд 6 и программа "не отвечает"
Intel core i5-6400 процессор
8ГБ RAM оператив.
Radeon R9 380 видеокарта
1ТБ HDD
В диспетчере задач eclipse грузит ЦП на 70-85%

Comment: `в него допилил aCute для написания C# кода` и с этого проблемы и начались? :)

Comment: Я раньше вообще не пользовался Eclipse, только-только установил